# given lognormal distribution, find expected value of its function

Tags: probability

I know that $Y(t)$ is a lognormal function with $$E[\log(Y(t)]=\log(Y_0)-10t$$ and $$Var(\log(Y(t))=2t$$

Given this information, how do I find $$E[(Y(t)+3)^2]?$$

I'm guessing I need to somehow use the formula for the continuous expected value, but I'm not sure how to put it all together

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using the rule of the lazy statistician: Let $Y = r(X)$ for a function $r$, then $E(Y) = E(r(X)) = \int r(x)f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: @Zoë Clark yes, that's exactly what I'm using...

Answer (score 0):

You know the mean and variance of the underlying normal distribution.  I'll rewrite them as $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ to save space: these are the stated functions of $t$.

Then $E[Y(t)] = e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$ and $Var(Y(t)) = \left(e^{\sigma^2}-1\right)e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}$ as with all [log-normal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) so $E[Y(t)^2] = e^{2\mu+2\sigma^2}$.

You want  $E[Y(t)^2]+6E[Y(t)]+9$